# How to properly Redirect with React Router 4?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-v4

A little background. I am using Firebase Authentication (GitHub, Twitter and Facebook), when the user gets authenticated, the app should redirect to `Updater` component from the `SocialButtonList` component.

Now I am trying to use Redirect `to: string` when the user gets authenticated, but for some reason is not working, maybe I am misunderstanding the docs.

My top level container

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/updater' component={Updater} />
          <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
          <Route component={NoMatch}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  ); 
}
```

Login.js

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Content align='center'>
      ...
      <SocialButtonList size={SOCIAL_BUTTON_SIZE_BIG} />
      ...
    </Content>
  );
}
```

SocialButtonList.js 
This component handles the authentication logic and upon authenticating I call `authHandler` and from here I am attempting to redirect to the 'Updater' component.

```
authHandler = authData => {
  if (authData) {
    <Redirect to='/updater' />
    console.log('AUTHENTICATED');
  } else {
    console.info('User is signed out!');
  }
}
```

In console I can see `AUTHENTICATED` message, but the app does not redirect. How can I properly redirect to `Updater` component?

**Update** I found a way to redirect using `withRouter`. See my answer below in the answer section.

Comment: See this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow - basically if you need to redirect, you make sure you render the redirect! Or you can use the `withRouter` and access the history

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found my answer using `withRouter` instead of `Redirect`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
authHandler = authData => {
  if (authData) {
    //<Redirect to={Updater} />
    this.props.history.push('/updater');
    console.log('AUTHENTICATED');
  } else {
    console.info('User is signed out!');
  }
}
...
export default withRouter(SocialButtonList);
```

This successfully redirects to `Updater` component.

Now I am wondering, is there a way to get `Redirect` to work?